# For In with closure and function creation issues

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to create a wrapper function that takes all the function properties of an object (obj) and wraps them with another function ( p() ).

This code illustrates what I mean.

```
//Setup code
function p(input){
    //do stuff
    return new_output;
}
obj = {
    prop1: function(){...},
    prop2: function(){...},
    prop3: function(){...}
 }

//Here's the wrapper function
r = new R(obj);

//Expected behaviour
r.prop1(a1,a2); //Just like saying p(obj.prop1(a1,a2))
```

Here's my attempt at the implementation

```
function R (obj) {
    for (var member in obj) {
            //Mirrors obj's members
        this[member] = function (args) {
            var fn,inner_member = member;
                    //Convert to array for 'apply'
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args,0);

            fn = obj[member];

                    //Returns unexpected values, poo...
            console.log(inner_member);
            return p( fn.apply(fn,args) );
        }
    };

}
```

Unfortunately, whenever I run r.prop1(), the console, via console.log, returns the wrong member, "prop3" and obj[member] returns "obj.prop3". Everything is wrong.

I think this has to do with the closure and how the newly created member member functions are looking outside their scope.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** David Flanagan's Javascript: The Definitive Guide answers this question pretty much directly in Chapter 8, section 3. That section is on closures and the last example mirrors what I wrote above. The key to understanding my problem is that functions are invoked in the same scope chain as they're defined. A function is an object AND related scope chain. AKA, a closure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `member` variable referenced by the functions you're generating in the `for` loop is the same `member` variable.

This is because JavaScript *does not have block scope, just function scope.* It's a common issue.

One solution is to invoke a function in the loop, passing in `member` so that it becomes part of a new variable scope.

```
function R (obj) {

// --------v---- use var to declare variables in order to avoid implicit globals
    for (var member in obj) {      // ...thanks to @CMS for the reminder.
        createMember( member );
    }

    function createMember( mem ) {
            //Mirrors obj's members
        this[ mem ] = function (args) {
            var fn,inner_member = mem;
                    //Conver to array for 'apply'

   // Don't forget to use .call-----------v
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args,0);

            fn = obj[ mem ];

            console.log(inner_member);
            return p( fn.apply(fn,args) );
        };
    }
}
```

Now the value of `member` in each iteration in the loop is pass as an argument into a separate function invocation, which creates a new variable scope each time.

Because each new function is part of each unique variable scope, each one is referencing a different `mem` variable (or parameter).

---

There are other variations on the same concept:

```
function R (obj) {
    for (var member in obj) {
        this[ member ] = createMember( member );
    }

    function createMember( mem ) {
            //Mirrors obj's members
        return function (args) {
            var fn,inner_member = mem;
                    //Conver to array for 'apply'

   // Don't forget to use .call-----------v
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args,0);

            fn = obj[ mem ];

            console.log(inner_member);
            return p( fn.apply(fn,args) );
        };
    }
}
```

This is the same, except that it *returns* a function from the invocation to be assigned to `this[ member ]`. Same principle though.

---

Other people prefer to use an IIFE *(immediately invoked function expression)* instead of a named function.

```
function R (obj) {
    for (var member in obj) {
        (function( mem ) {
                //Mirrors obj's members
            this[ mem ] =  function (args) {
                var fn,inner_member = mem;
                    //Conver to array for 'apply'

   // Don't forget to use .call----------------v
                args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args,0);

                fn = obj[ mem ];

                console.log(inner_member);
                return p( fn.apply(fn,args) );
            };
        })( member );
    }
}
```

...though I think it's less clear, and a little less efficient.

---

**EDIT:** Added `var` to `member` variable to avoid implicit global. Thanks to [@CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms).

**EDIT:** Changed `Array.prototype.slice(args,0)` to `Array.prototype.slice.call(args,0)`

---

**EDIT:**

This isn't related to any issue, but if all you're doing is passing on the `arguments` when the wrapper invokes the original function, you can get rid of...

```
args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args,0);
```

And just pass on the original `arguments` object:

```
return p( fn.apply( fn,arguments ) );
```

No need to convert it to an Array.

Comment: Also, don't forget to declare the `member` variable... `for (var member in obj)`

Comment: @CMS: Good catch. That's *at least* the 3rd time you've caught me forgetting to fix that. ;o) Fixed.

Comment: I fixed slice.call and added var member in the original example. Thanks

Comment: @Christian: You're welcome, although it's `slice.call`, not `slice.slice`. ;o)

Comment: It's 5am here in Thailand, gimme a break.