# JavaScript event using reflected property doesn't return can't see rest of array

Tags: javascript, setattribute

Working with JavaScript in IE, I used the reflected property but the problem is I have 12 items and all of alert `12`.

When I use `setAttribute`, there's no problem.

What I have so far:

```
    var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
    for (i in items)    {
        newdiv = document.createElement("div");

        //newdiv.setAttribute("class","box");
        //newdiv.setAttribute("id",items[i]);
        //newdiv.setAttribute("ondblclick","chkItem("+items[i]+");");

        newdiv.className = "box";
        newdiv.id = items[i];
        newdiv.ondblclick = function() {alert(items[i])}
        newdiv.innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + items[i];
        document.getElementById("items").appendChild(newdiv);
    }
```

Comment: What is the content of `items`?

Comment: Just numbers. I edited the code.

Comment: The problem is **there is only one variable called `i`**. This is a very common question on SO, lemme see what duplicates we can find...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access outside variable in loop from Javascript closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/access-outside-variable-in-loop-from-javascript-closure)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904366/for-in-with-closure-and-function-creation-issues

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: There really needs to be a "FAQ"-style question on this everything can be linked to -- the trick is *knowing* what to look for :p

Comment: Wouldn't function (){ alert(this.id); } work? see Answer below.

Comment: Thank you very much, all of you. The real problem is that I questioned so early without study.

Comment: This is a shame. Anyway, by your favor, now I can make the website about snack and candy. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
newdiv.ondblclick = function() {alert(items[i])}
```

to this:

```
newdiv.ondblclick = (function(item) { return function() {alert(item)} })(items[i])
```

Look up [Closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), which is what is screwing you up in this case. When you create an anonymous function using `function() { }`, you are creating a closure that is bound in the scope that it was created. So inside your closure, your variable `i` is the same variable that you were using in the loop. So when you double click on an item, the loop is already finished and `i == 12`. It would be the same as if you put an `alert(i);` directly after your `for(i in items) { }` loop.

So, with that in mind, how does my second example fix that?

Well, it uses a self-executing anonymous function that accepts one variable, `item`. This function returns a closure, which is bound inside *its* scope. The outer closure is immediately executed, passing in `items[i]`, which creates a stable scope for the variable that you want to live in.

Closures can be a little mind bending if you aren't used to them, but understanding them is a big part to getting functional programming using JavaScript.

SetAttribute works because you are creating a new string that evaluates each time through the loop, rather than late-referencing the variable `i`.

*PS*

Its probably a bad idea to use a `for( in ) {}` on an array. You might get unexpected results, it should loop through all the propertys of the object not just the items in the array. its probably safer to use a regular `for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Because within the function call for double click you are referencing the element which you have already defined an ID value for... why not just use.

```
newdiv.ondblclick = function() {alert(this.id)}
```

Where `this` is the newdiv element.

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ALxFW/)

Comment: Sometimes a second look it all it takes. No question is a stupid question, however some answers are.. ;)

Comment: just realized too that the link i had provided was to the main page for jsfiddle. Forgot to save the fiddle before I copied out the url. Duh!